# No se está creando un campo de tipo objeto (creado a partir de un schema) en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Intento configurar una API para añadir al carrito un producto. Estoy usando express js y mongoDB como back.

Al intentar incluir un nuevo campo de tipo array que contiene el objeto con un `productSchema` y la cantidad de ese producto en el schema de `user` MongoDb no lo reconoce y por tanto no está incluyendo ese campo de `product` en el documento.

Código de userSchema:

```javascript
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { productSchema } = require("./product");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: {
  required: true,
  type: String,
  trim: true,
},
email: {
  required: true,
  type: String,
  trim: true,
  validate: {
    validator: (value) => {
      const re =
        /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
      return value.match(re);
    },
    message: "Please enter a valid email address",
  },
},
password: {
  required: true,
  type: String,
},
address: {
  type: String,
  default: "",
},
type: {
  type: String,
  default: "user",
},
//nuevo campo que intento agregar
cart: [
  {
//campo que no se está creando en MongoDB
    product: productSchema,
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
],
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Código del servicio de la API

```javascript
userRouter.post('/api/add-to-cart', auth, async (req, res) => {
try{
   const { id } = req.body;
   //busca el producto en la base de datos
   const producto = await Product.findById(id);
   let user = await User.findById(req.user);
  

   if(user.cart.length == 0){
       user.cart.push({producto, quantity: 1});
   }else{
   
     let isProductEqual = false;
     for(let i = 0; i<user.cart.length; i++){
       console.log(user.cart[i]);
       
      //está línea de código me arroja un error de "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')" al momento de probar la API ya que el campo product no ha sido creado correctamente
       if(user.cart[i].product._id.equals(producto._id)){
           isProductEqual = true;
       }
     }
       if(isProductEqual){
           let producttt = user.cart.find((x)=> x.product._id.equals(producto._id));
           producttt.quantity += 1;
       }else{
           user.cart.push({producto, quantity: 1});
       }


   }
   user = await user.save();
   res.json(user);
}catch(e){
   res.status(500).json({error: e.message});
}
   

   });
```

Al probar la API me he dado cuenta de que en MongoDB no se está registrando el campo de product dentro del campo array cart, solo se crea el de quantity y el autogenerado _id

He ultrarevisado todas las posibles causas y no encontrado nada anormal (las declaraciones de importación y exportación está bien)

Gracias por la orientación que me puedan dar ;)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debe ser `product` no `producto`.

```
       }else{
           //El problema es el nombre de la variable.
           user.cart.push({product:producto, quantity: 1});
       }
```

Habrá que ultrarevisar con un poco de calma. :D

Comment: ajjajaja tienes razón siempre siempre se le pasa a uno algo! Mucha gracias!! me gaste horas tratando de dar con el problema y para saber que era eso jajajaj ;O)

Comment: @NicolasSicard Así es my friend. Son los que más nos hacen batallar.